# Will angular remove typescript or html comment during the compilation process?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Angular compile typescript and turn them into javascript with the use of `ng serve` command. My question is, does it default remove all comment inside html files, typescript. Or else you have ability to do this by setting the option in file like `angular.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, comments are not deleted. If you want to delete comments from Html file you just need to build your app in production mode: `ng build --prod`.

If you want to delete comments from `*.ts` files you need to set `removeComments` in your `tsconfig.json` file (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#removeComments) like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": true,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```